# how to switch two tables in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I have a rails application, connected to a postgres db.
I am trying to migrate 2 table, and switch the names.

before migration I have tableA and tableB with records, and a model for each table, i want to switch the table names and models. 
I know in need to query all the data from tableA a into a list, change the table, query all the data from tableB into new tableA, change tableB and insert the list into new tableB.
Is there any default activeRecord function? or any better way or best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to change the table structure / contents? If it is literally renaming the tables and model names, from say Model Cat to Model Dog and visa versa, then try:

```
class RenameTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  rename_table :cats, :temp_cats
  rename_table :dogs, :cats
  rename_table :temp_cats, :dogs
end
```

We need to have the temp name as otherwise we'll get duplicate table name errors.

That's your tables sorted, now just either rename your model file names from models/cat.rb to models/dog.rb, or simply swap out the content between them.